# Explanation of Epsilon in IEEE 754

Tags: javascript, ieee-754

Epsilon is the smallest value in a number encoding scheme that can be added to `1` to generate a number that has a distinctly different representation.

Can anyone help me intuit why the loss of precision is greater in the latter example here?

```js
console.log(Number.EPSILON > (0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3)) // true
```

```js
console.log(Number.EPSILON > (10000.1 + 10000.2 - 20000.3)) // false
```

Is it that the significand required to exactly represent many easily-written decimal numbers is larger than the 52 bits available, and that therefore an inaccuracy is introduced by truncation. This inaccuracy is then multiplied by the exponent, and if the exponent is large, the inaccuracy is magnified?

Comment: The key part of the definition you quoted is *added to 1*.  The value 100 has a larger exponent than 1.

Comment: MDN - "Note that the absolute accuracy of floating numbers decreases as the number gets larger, because the exponent grows while the mantissa's accuracy stays the same." - meaning that the larger the number, the larger the error. Your example uses tens of thousands so the error is larger than Number.EPSILON.

Comment: The reason we call the format "floating point" is because the decimal point **floats**. That is, there is a fixed number of bits representing a number but you can put the decimal point anywhere in that number to make the number larger or smaller. So as the number gets larger it logically makes sense that you lose precision because you are trading what digits you want on the left of the decimal point with how many digits you can have on the right of the decimal point.

Comment: "*Is it that the significand required to exactly represent many easily-written decimal numbers is larger than the 52 bits available*" - [Yes](https://floating-point-gui.de)

Comment: Re “Epsilon is the smallest value in a number encoding scheme that can be added to 1 to generate a number that has a distinctly different representation”: No, it is not. The so-called “machine epsilon” is the difference between 1 and the next representable number. For example, in the IEEE-754 binary64 format used for the JavaScript `Number` format, the epsilon is 2^−52, since the next `Number` greater than 1 is 1+2^−52. However, if the smallest `Number` you can add to 1 to get a greater number is 2^−53 + 2^−105, because the sum will be rounded to the next representable number, 1+2^−52.

Comment: OK, thank you. So `Number.EPSILON` is the machine epsilon for binary64?

Answer (score 3):

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/EPSILON#description):

> The EPSILON property has a value of approximately `2.2204460492503130808472633361816E-16`, or `2-52`. This is the smallest value that can be added to 1 to get a distinct number, because double precision floating point format only has 52 bits to represent the mantissa, and the lowest bit has a significance of 2^-52.
>
> Note that the **absolute accuracy** of floating numbers **decreases as the number gets larger**, because the **exponent grows** while the **mantissa's accuracy stays the same**.

The error accumulated in `0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3` is smaller than EPSILON, and this is actually true for `10.1 + 10.2 - 10.3` and `100.1 + 100.2 - 200.3`:

```js
console.log(Number.EPSILON > (100.1 + 100.2 - 200.3)); // true
```

But in the thousands, the margin of error created by the conversion to IEEE-754 is already larger than EPSILON:

```js
console.log(Number.EPSILON > (1000.1 + 1000.2 - 2000.3)); // false
```

And to drive the point home, 100 million (`100000000.1`) already has an error of `-0.1`, which means `100000000.1` is treated as `100000000`. Try out some other values in this [converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) that displays the number in IEEE-754 format and the error the conversion produces.

Comment: Thank you. Base-ten `10,000.1` is `100,001e-1`. Base-ten `100,001` is base-2 `11000011010100001`, which has seventeen significant digits in base-2. Base-ten `10,000.1` is `100,002e-1`. Base-ten `100,002` is `11000011010100010`, which has sixteen significant digits in base-2. The sum of the mantissas is base-ten `200,003`, which is `110000110101000011` , which has eighteen significant digits in base-2. IEEE 754 stores numbers with fifty-two bits for mantissa, eleven bits for the exponent and one for the sign. Why is any imprecision developed in these calculations?

Comment: @BenAston Because IEEE754  floats do not use `e-1`, which would be `×10⁻¹`. They use `×2ⁿ`.

Comment: Thank you. So the intuition is that the exact significand for whatever base-10 `10,000.1` corresponds to in a binary format that uses significands and exponents, is longer than the 52 bits available for the significand in binary64?

Comment: @BenAston check the converter linked in the answer. It shows that `10000.1` is really stored as `10000.099609375`. In general, whole integers can be stored correctly (up to a Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER) and as for decimal numbers - very few can. For example multiples of 1/2 (0.5) can be stored correct;y: 1/4, 1/8, 1/16, etc. But for any other decimal, *chances are* it's will have a problem.

Comment: The MDN is wrong to state “This is the smallest value that can be added to 1 to get a distinct number.” Adding 2^−53+2^−105 to 1 yields a distinct number, 1+2^−52. See my comment on the question.

Comment: @EricPostpischil So make it "can be added exactly…"?

Answer (score 1):

The EPSILON is a minimum *percentage* difference between two values

If you try

```
console.log((10000.1 + 10000.2 - 20000.3) / Number.EPSILON)
// > 16384 
console.log((0.1 + 0.2 - 0.3) / Number.EPSILON)
// > 0.25
```

you will see, that the error in EPSILONs is lesser then accordinate values (20000.3 and 0.3)

Comment: The `EPSILON` is not a percentage because it is not per one-hundredth of anything; there is no scaling of 100 in it. And while it behaves roughly as ratio, it is not purely a ratio either, as the distance between representable numbers if fixed for each binade, so that distance jumps at powers of two; it is not continuous like a ratio.

Answer (score 1):

In positional number systems, each digit represents a value corresponding to its position multiplied by the base. So `20` in base ten means 2 x 10<sup>1</sup> + 0 x 10<sup>0</sup> = twenty. And `10` in base two (binary) means 1 x 2<sup>1</sup> + 0 x 2<sup>0</sup> = two.

Simple enough. But what about fractions? In order to represent these values, each digit to the right of a decimal point represents a value corresponding to its position DIVIDED by the base. So `0.2` in base ten means 0 x 10<sup>0</sup> + 2 x 10<sup>-1</sup> = two-tenths. Negative exponents represent division.

So how do we represent, for example, the base ten value `0.2` in binary?

We repeatedly find the largest divisor of the value (or remainder) that is a power of two, until the remainder is zero or we run out of bits to store the number.

```
0 .  1   1   1   1    1    1     1     1     1     1
    1/2 1/4 1/8 1/16 1/32 1/64 1/128 1/256 1/512 1/1024
```

In binary:

```
  Binary Value       |    Remainder in Base Ten
                     |       0.2                         
     0.001           |       0.2 - (1/8) = 0.075       
     0.0011          |       0.075 - (1/16) = 0.0125                    
     0.0011001       |       0.0125 - (1/128) = 0.0046875
     0.00110011      |       0.0046875 - (1/256) = 0.00078125
     0.00110011001   |       0.00078125 - (1/2048) = 0.00048828125
     0.001100110011  |       0.00048828125 - (1/4096) = 0.000244140625
     ...and so on, in a recurring pattern, forever
```

Clearly this won't fit in 53 bits.<sup>1</sup>

As it happens, IEEE 754 has a slightly different number encoding scheme, but the number still recurs. And so: the 53-bit significand<sup>2</sup> will be filled with a recurring number until truncation. Then the exponent will be applied, meaning the value of the least significant significand bit will be multiplied (I think) by 2<sup>exponent</sup>: ie. it will be magnified for numbers of large magnitude (positive and negative).

In other words: the truncated significant digits are made more significant, the larger the exponent is.

Or, in other, other words: in a number encoding scheme with a fixed number of bits for the significand, the exactitude with which numbers can be represented decreases as the exponent grows larger.

### Footnotes

<sup>1</sup> The JavaScript `Number` format has a 53-bit significand. 52 bits are encoded in the primary significand field, and one bit is encoded via the exponent field.

<sup>2</sup> “Significand” is the preferred term for the fraction portion of a floating-point number. “Mantissa” is an old term for the fraction portion of a logarithm. Mantissas are logarithmic; adding a value to a significand multiplies the number represented. Significands are linear; adding a value to a significand adds to the value represented, as scaled by the exponent.